# How to mount/quickly sync a GitHub repository on Amazon EC2

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, github-api

So I'm using an Amazon EC2 server as a test server of my production site.(Linux + Apache + PHP), and I have the same thing as in my GitHub as a repository.

Right now I'm making changes on my GitHub and I want to see the result in my website right away. I figured that I can just "mount" the git to a folder so there will be a symbolic link. Say I can do this to my webroot, every time the server will load content from the github in real time since it's mounted there.

Is there a way I can do this?  Or there are better ways to deal with GitHub?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is via a deployment script such as [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). This script will basically automate the process of logging into your remote server, pulling repo content from GitHub & even setting system configs & other params to get the app to work.